# Can't get threaded connector all the way into shower faucet. Do they need to go all the way?

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

We're installing a small corner shower in one of our washrooms, and I'm having an issue with the threaded inlet/outlet connections on the faucet.

I'm using Sharkbite, and bought some threaded-on-one-side/Sharkbite-on-the-other straight connectors for attaching everything to the faucet. The problem is I can only get them to thread about 2/3 of the way into any of the four spots on the faucet. I've tried with a wrench and they just refuse to go any farther than that.

The faucet set is Glacier Bay, which I've since found out is a pretty crap brand, so maybe that's the problem. Alternatively, maybe the threads on the Sharkbite connectors are too big, but I have a hard time believing that.

Is it a problem if the connectors don't go 100% of the way in?

I should point out, that for at least a few weeks, the wall behind the shower will be wide open, so I *could* try just threading the connectors as far as they'll go and keep a close eye on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be necessary to see all the threads "disappear" for the two ends to be fully engaged and tightened.

You could measure each end (male and female) to determine if they are substantially different to determine if the shorter of the two is fully engaged.

After you cover the male end threads with a couple winds of Teflon tape and thread them together very snug, (be careful not to over tighten) the important thing is that the connection does not leak.  If you don't leak, you are all set, regardless if any threads on one side (feed line or faucet) are showing.